# Laravel store data thru model

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I dont know how else to label the title. Anyone have ideas go ahead and make a suggested edit.

I have a series of Models for the database in my application.

I can currently add a global scope to the model and have the model automatically add a "where" clause on my queries to the database on a key:value pair. This is working great.

```
class Customers extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';

    protected static function boot() {

        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('companyRecordID', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('companyRecordID', Auth::guard('user')->user()->companyRecordID);
        });

    }
}
```

I am having troubles trying to identify if this can be done; Id like to be able to store the "companyRecordID" from the `Auth::guard('user')->user()->companyRecordID` automatically when a database record is created. Similar to `created_at` and `updated_at` are created automatically without requiring code from the controller to define.

Can someone direct me to what I should be looking for. Ive spent a few hours trying to google key word pairs to find an answer with no avail.

Comment: you want to add a `companyRecordID` attribute to every model saved?

Comment: I want to add the companyRecordID with the value from auth for every record saved from said model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Models to create the records you can listen for the `creating` event for the Model and then add any additional fields you may need. You can create a listener for the `creating` event on `Customers`:

```
Customers::creating(function ($customer) {
    if (auth('user')->user()) {
        $customer->companyRecordID = auth('user')->user()->companyRecordID;
    }
});
```

You can throw that in a Service Provider's `boot` method or your Model's `boot` method. If you throw it in the Model's `boot` method you may want to adjust to using `static::` instead of `Customers::`.

Comment: I would like to be able to keep it unique to the model just as I have for adding a whereclause on every query that-- that model runs from the controller.

Comment: keep what unique to the model? this is for the Customer model only

Comment: Correct; you mentioned to add to service providers boot though.

Comment: or your model's boot method

Comment: no, sorry, in my example I named your model correctly, which is wrong ... `Customers::` just adjust `Customer` to `Customers`, your model name ... or change it to `static::`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you got your answer but,

On your model please use `protected $fillable`

```
protected $fillable = ['','',''];
protected $table = 'customers';
```

also, you can use **Relationships** to optimize your codes.

Comment: Yes; thank you for mentioning that. Ive been in development for a few years now and plan on going back and making sure all fillable fields, and model "settings" are defined and protected to optimize my code. I just didnt want to have to constantly be adjusting models along with everything else. Im just getting to the point where I can start to structure multi-tenancy so I was seeking how I can implement said multi-tenancy thru the model in a clean method rather than updating over 200 controllers.